# You forgot to enter your password

Tags: php

For some reason I whenever I am attempting to run the PHP it will only say, "You forgot to enter your password." Any suggestions as to what I am missing? The code itself appears to be error free...? I have tried a multitude of options and still nothing seems to be fixing this error. I have a database which is it connecting to appropriately and it just seems like it is not pulling the password1 field.

```
 <?php
echo mysql_error(); 
// Send NOTHING to the Web browser prior to the session_start() line!
// Check if the form has been submitted.
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
require_once ('../../mysql_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.
$errors = array(); // Initialize error array.
// Check for an email address.
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
} else {
    $e = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
}
// Check for a password.
if (empty($_POST['password1'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
} else {
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);
}
if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.
    /* Retrieve the user_id and first_name for 
    that email/password combination. */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE email='$e' AND  
    password1='$password1','$password2'"; 
    $result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query.
    $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
    if ($row) { // A record was pulled from the database.
        //Set the session data:
        session_start(); 
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row[1];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row[2];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row[3];
        $_SESSION['password1'] = $row[4];
        $_SESSION['password2'] = $row[5];
        $_SESSION['registration_date'] = $row[6]; 

        // Redirect:
        header("Location:loggedin.php");
        exit(); // Quit the script.
    } else { // No record matched the query.
        $errors[] = 'The email address and password entered do not match     
those on file.'; // Public message.
    }
} // End of if (empty($errors)) IF.
mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
} else { // Form has not been submitted.
$errors = NULL;
} // End of the main Submit conditional.

// Begin the page now.
$page_title = 'Login';
include ('header.php');
if (!empty($errors)) { // Print any error messages.
echo '<h1 id="mainhead">Error!</h1>
<p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error.
    echo " - $msg<br />\n";
}
echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';
}

// Create the form.
?>
<body bgcolor="#c0c6c6"> 
<h2>Please, login here.</h2>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="40" /> </p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>

<?php
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.  Please please please use prepared statements for your SQL.

Answer (score 7):

Your form includes `name="password"`, but your PHP is looking for `$_POST['password1']`. These names MUST match for it to work!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However once I changed the name I received:
    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,     boolean given in /home/Home/login.php on line 25

Comment: @user2293452 That's because your query failed - unrelated to the original question. ^^  Just by looking at it `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$e' AND  
    password1='$password1','$password2'"` you shouldn't expect to work, and you are creating the variables from `$_POST['password1']` still as well.

Comment: I can see at least 8 errors or basic coding malpractices in your code, but at Jon said that was not what this question is about ;)

Comment: Still pretty new to PHP and I've been trying to get this to pull the password for the past four hours now.

Comment: Well, tell me, what is `$password2` and what business does it have in your query?

Comment: @user2293452 if you've been working on this for hours, I'd suggest a very simple [tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html) for creating a login script to look at and learn from.  Though, I will note that it uses `mysql_` and should be moved to PDO or MySQLi soon - but it's something that should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, I nixed the 'password1' and just kept everything as 'password', and then changed:
 if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
  $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
 } else {
  $p = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
 }
along with
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE email='$e' AND password='$p'"; 

But still receiving the error on line 25 along with the page now saying that, "The email address and password entered do not match those on file."

Comment: @Kolink for the sign up form I have a password field and then a confirmation password field named respectively password2. In the database table I have password1 for the password field and password2 for the confirmation passsword.

Comment: @Jon thank you, but I've run across this webpage already and it didn't do me much good...

Comment: @user2293452 As an aside: trying to drag people through all the errors in your task is Frowned Upon (tm). Ideally you should try to work through those yourself by debugging your code and researching a solution, not exploit the fact you already have someone's attention.